# Multimodule project - Dagger

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

In my Android project I have my:

- **core** library module
- **ui_add_credit_card** library module
- **app** as application module

In the **core** an `AppComponent` is defined:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = {
                AppModule.class,
                NetworkModule.class,
                ViewModelFactoryModule.class,
        }
)
public interface AppComponent {
```

and a special module for ViewModules that is bind module `ViewModelFactoryModule`:

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelFactoryModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(viewModelFactory: DaggerViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(SplashViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindSplashViewModel(viewModel: SplashViewModel): ViewModel
...
```

`DaggerViewModelFactory` is a special ViewModelProvider.Factory that will take care of ViewModel key naming so injecting Activities/Fragments don't need to care about it:

```
class DaggerViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
        private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        try {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }    }
}
```

That all works fine :)

The problem is when I want to create additional `AddCreditCardComponent` and `AddCreditCardViewModelModule` for separate project module **ui_add_credit_card**.

```
@Component(
        dependencies = [AppComponent::class],
        modules = [
            AddCreditCardViewModelModule::class
        ])
interface AddCreditCardComponent {

    fun inject(creditCardRegisterActivity: CreditCardRegisterActivity)
}
```

```
@Module
abstract class AddCreditCardViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(CreditCardViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindCreditCardRegistrationViewModel(
            viewModel: CreditCardRegistrationViewModel
    ): ViewModel

}
```

I get the following error:

> AddCreditCardComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

Any help? I assumed ViewModelProvider.Factory should be provided by my `ViewModelFactoryModule` but it doesn't happen :(

Comment: Might want to watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fn5s8_CYJI for a better approach.

Comment: Thx I'll watch it ! But my approach is quite similar to Plaid app and Ben Weiss article https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/dependency-injection-in-a-multi-module-project-1a09511c14b7

Comment: You're using component depdenencies. As opposed to subcomponents, you don't have access to everything the component dependency has, so you'd have to explicitly add a "getter" (provision method) for the `ViewModelFactory` to your `AppComponent` if you want access to it from another dependent component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by creating module `AddCreditCardViewModelModule` in a different way (@Provide instead of @Binds) and I had to create specialized ViewModel.Factory that will care about added ViewModel instantiation.

```
@Module
object AddCreditCardViewModelModule {

    @JvmStatic @Provides
    fun provideAddCreditCardViewModelFactory(
            adyenApi: AdyenApi,
            paymentController: PaymentController
    ) = AddCreditCardViewModelFactory(adyenApi, paymentController)

}
```

also (thx to [David Medenjak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1837367/david-medenjak)) it was crucial to make sure dependencies (e.g. `AdyenApi`) from `AppComponent` are exposed as a "getter". Otherwise `AddCreditCardComponent` won't have access to it.

Cheers!

Comment: A lot samples of depennt component could be found in Plaid app: https://github.com/android/plaid